# "The requested content does not exist." 404 error with an Angular Static Website (Azure)

Tags: angular, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-website-hosting

I have an **Azure Storage Account** where I've enabled Static Website. I have released and deployed my Angular website through the Azure Devops pipeline onto the storage account.

I have done this before, and the same error occurred. When adding the `useHash` code, the problem was solved:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

But this time the `Not Found` error still occurs.

[image: error]

I have used the URL provided by Azure itself (see below). Is there a solution to this?

[image: url]

EDIT:

This is the YAML for its release:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WebAppTest'
    azureSubscription: 'some resource group'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: testsomestorage
    ContainerName: '$web'
    sasTokenTimeOutInMinutes: 240
```

Comment: Could you please check your folder structure in `$web` container?

Comment: @JimXu Yes, the folder structure is as follows: $web > WebAppProd > P****Frontend.

Comment: As far as I knew, we should host `index,html` under container `$web`  root level.

Comment: @JimXu Hmm, interesting. Because as far as I know, I have done this before (it is an automated release through **Azure Devops**), it'd worked. But I'm going to give it a try to host `index.html` under the `$web` root level.

Comment: @JimXu I have added the release YAML of the AzureFileCopy to the container.

Comment: @JimXu Fixed. See my new answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this issue was easy after trying several things.
Below you see the folder structure of where the artifacts are stored in:

[image: Folder structure of linked artifacts]

I had selected the `WebAppTest (Build)` as the source path instead of the second one below called `'****Frontend'`.

After I changed this, the website was finally working.